# Angular mat-menu appearing outside page

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 8 to develop an app where I'd like to use a customised context menu. I'm using Material v8.2.3 for this, and tried to implement the basic example from [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/gxlgpxjdnar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts).

However, when clicking on the button now, the context menu appears at the bottom of the page rather than at the location of the click (or on the button). Any ideas why this is happening? (See attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6D9d.png))

Much like their example, I've only included the necessary HTML (tried to wrap it in a div but made no difference):

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

I've used exactly the same imports and exports they've used in the example.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular] on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is not space for `items` to display,  but You can "play" with the properties `xPosition` and `yPosition`

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" yPosition="below">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

you can also use a `class` and set `margin-top`.

[Here is an official guide for positioning](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MenuPositionX)