# I am using mat-menu of angular/material V15 in mat-tool bar but the menu list is not appearing below the menu heading

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following code:

```
<mat-toolbar id="header" style="display: inline-flex;">
   
    <img  src="/assets/images/medlogo2.png" class="smallLogo">
    <h1 routerLink="/home" class="title">{{company}}</h1>
    
    <button class='header-list' mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="projects"><h2>Projects</h2></button>
    <mat-menu #projects="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>The Palms at Mayfair</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Pilgrim</button>
    </mat-menu>

    <button class='header-list' mat-flat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="services"><h2>Services</h2></button>
    <mat-menu #services="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>Property Management</button>
      <button mat-menu-item>Property Maintenance</button>
    </mat-menu>
 
    <div class="header-list" >
        <h2 routerLink="/about">About Us</h2> 
     </div>
    
 </mat-toolbar>
```

....CSS

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a0d5e5;
    color: white;
  }

  .title {
   
      margin-left: 10px;
      padding-top: 10px;

     }

  .smallLogo{
        height: 50px;
      }
  .miniLogo{
        height: 25px;
      }
  .header-list {
 
     display: inline-flex;
     padding-top: 15px;

   margin-left: auto;
  }
    

  h1:hover {
    background-color: rgb(242, 232, 243);

    cursor: pointer;
  }
  h2:hover {
    background-color: rgb(242, 232, 243);

    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

with two of my menu links having menus....normally the menus would fall immediately below the link item as default. They are actually falling on what looks like a new page...outside the toolbar block. I just started this work so I am using the latest angular/material version which is Version 15. I would appreciate any help on this...thanks

I have discovered a similar question without an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61117203/angular-mat-menu-appearing-outside-page?rq=1)

Comment: check your .css and if you include the property (theme/import). Your code looks like work, see [this stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu7sfp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoolbar-basic-example.html)

Comment: So normally ng new init gives you a style.css file with the theme like this: @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }.   In v15 a blank .css/scss is produced. I tried using the theming in your stackblitz but I got the same incorrect result.

Comment: Apparently the v15 scaffolding as messed up both the style.css and the index.html file also when corrected the mat-flatten-button directive don't work. So restoring the files will have the menu position correctly but not flattened.